# Why can't I combine Reduce with paste when using "*" as a character?

Tags: r, string

I'm trying to get the output "1*2*4*5" from `(function(x) Reduce(paste0(toString("*")),x))(c(1,2,4,5))`, but no matter how I manipulate Reduce, paste0, and the asterisks, I'm either getting error messages or the asterisks being treated as multiplication (giving 40). Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Reduce` uses a function with two arguments to which it applies the previous result and the next element of the vector. Therefore, you need a function of both `x` and `y`:

```
Reduce(function(x,y)paste0(x,"*",y),c(1,2,4,5))
#[1] "1*2*4*5"
```

As an aside, you can provide an initial value to be applied as `x` for the first element of the vector with `init =`.

```
Reduce(function(x,y)paste0(x,"*",y),c(1,2,4,5), init = 0)
#[1] "0*1*2*4*5"
```

One thing you may have tried was this:

```
Reduce(paste0("*"),c(1,2,4,5))
#[1] 40
```

This applies the multiplication operator to `x` and `y`, because `paste0("*")` evaluates to `"*"`.

Comment: So what caused the multiplication? Some default that I missed?

Comment: See my edit, and if that doesn't answer your question, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

KISS method:
(with improvements as suggested by @nicola)

```
bar <- as.character(1:5)
 paste0(bar,sep="",collapse='*')
#[1] "1*2*3*4*5"
```

Comment: Was wondering how anybody didn't mention `collapse` and then saw your answer. However, why `unlist` and `as.character`? They look unnecessary.

Comment: @nicola -- you are correct that at least "most" of the time  the use of a character for the `collapse` argument will coerce numeric to char.  I like to be cautious.    `unlist` gives you a nice vector, which is what the OP asked for .

Comment: `paste` returns a character vector and not a list, so no need to `unlist` or `as.character` on the input, since `paste` itself will coerce if necessary. Did you try to just run `paste0(1:5,collapse="*")`?

Comment: @nicola  you are correct.  I must have been playing with  `strsplit` when I originally posted this answer, which does return a list.

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option is to use `paste` within `gsub`, e.g.,

```
x <- 1:5
gsub("\\s","*",Reduce(paste,x))
```

which gives

```
> gsub("\\s","*",Reduce(paste,x))
[1] "1*2*3*4*5"
```